# Dynamic HTML5 video shows white for some users in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, video

We have a header video that loads an image then lazy loads a video (mp4 and webm depending on browser). For some users in Firefox the HTML5 video source is white and for others it plays.

For me it shows white for my coworker it plays both of us have Macbook OS X and on the same version of Firefox.

Comment: Could be helpful to have a demo, or even your video tag code so that we can try it ourselfs... :-)

Comment: @ThaoD5 - http://gobiglabs.com/test-me/ this is just a test site. For me the image will fade out and no video shows. For some people it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try a video code generator.
See this generator » [The Wikies](http://v4e.thewikies.com/)

The Wikies will generate a code like this:

```
<video controls="controls" preload="none" poster="your-cover-image.jpg" width="640" height="480">
    <source src="your-video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="your-video.webm" type="video/webm" />
    <!-- other available formats -->

    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf" width="640" height="480">
        <param name="movie" value="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf"></param>
        <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
        <param name="wmode" value="transparent"></param>
        <param name="flashVars" value="config={'playlist':['https%3A%2F%2Fwww.your-domain.com%2Fimg%2Fyour-cover-image.jpg',{'url':'https%3A%2F%2Fwww.your-domain.com%2video%2Fyour-video.mp4','autoPlay':false}]}"></param>
        <img alt="Alternative Text" src="https://www.your-domain.com/img/your-cover-image.jpg" width="640" height="480" title="This video can't be loaded. Please, update your browser.">
    </object>
</video>
```

Please, test and let me know if works for you!
For me it works fine on IE7+, Firefox & Chrome.

Hope to help you!

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question.

Comment: The [test page](http://gobiglabs.com/test-me) works fine for me. Verify the firefox extensions and disable them to test. After that, try to change attributes to *controls="controls"* and *preload="none"*. I had a problem with preload *auto* on last week. Thanks for your comment, Rob! Maybe my text didn't help anyone :) Sorry my bad English too!